# Using a set of indices to select a subset of an array

Tags: list-manipulation, index

Let's say I have a 1D array `a`, I can use a list of indices `b` to select a subset of that array:

```
a = {1, 4, 3, 2}
b = {1, 2, 1}
a[[b]] (* Returns {1,4,1} *)
```

What if I have an array with `n` indices? For example, for `n=2`:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
b = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}
a[[b]] (*Returns: Part::pkspec1: The expression {{1,2},{2,1},{2,2}} cannot be used as a part specification. *)
```

I intend to use this for an array with four indices.

Comment: From reading the docs, I would think [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) doesn't work this way.  See the section "Possible Issues":  "Successive part extraction is not always equivalent to direct part extraction"

Comment: `Extract[]` is nice: `Extract[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
b = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};

a[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ b
```

> {2, 3, 4}

Comment: You could also write this as `a[[##]] & @@@ b`  (I think you originally had something like that, but with only one slot)

Comment: Is there an equivalent with function names instead of these operators? I'm new to Mathematica and although it works, I find this notation quite intractable.

Comment: `a[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ b` is equivalent to `Map[Function[spec, Part[a, Apply[Sequence, spec]]], b]`, However J.M.'s comment to use `Extract` is the best solution.